# Alternative to Acoustica Mixcraft for Chrome OS

Tags: audio, chrome-os, audio-recording

I am looking for an alternative to [Acoustica Mixcraft](http://www.acoustica.com/mixcraft/) which is audio recording software that runs on PCs. Here are my requirements,

- Reasonably priced (preferably free)
- Runs on a Google Chromebook (Chrome OS)
- Records audio
- Does not drain battery life quickly

Comment: What kind of audio recording software are you looking for? Please rewrite your question adding specific features

Comment: Say similar to Acoustica Mixcraft (which I use on PC)? [Question edited as you suggest.]

Comment: ok, I kind of reworded your question, add any additional requirements that you would like

Comment: Oh right; that does pretty much say it all @Tom , and so much more clearly; thanks again.

Comment: Are you excluding online options like Soundation?